# php code to insert multiple rows using for loop

Tags: php

I am getting value from column1 textbox like

```
column1 = 501,505,
```

Now I need to insert two rows in my table because there are two values present in column1 textbox like:

```
501

505
```

But my for loop insert all rows between 501 and 505.

```
$column1 = $_POST['column1 '];  
$arr = explode(",", rtrim($column1 , ', '));

$min = min($arr);
$max = max($arr);

for ($i = 1; $i <= $max; $i++)
{
$insertrow = $database->insertRow("INSERT INTO table (column1)  
VALUES  (:column1)", array(':column1'=>$column1));              
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `max($arr)` by `count($arr)`

```
$column1 = $_POST['column1 '];  
$arr = explode(",", rtrim($column1 , ', '));

$max = count($arr);

for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++)
{
$insertrow = $database->insertRow("INSERT INTO table (column1)  
VALUES  (:column1)", array(':column1'=>$arr[$i]));              
}
```

Comment: but this is inserting 1 and 2 in database....i need when i put 501,505, in textbox then it insert 501 in first row and 505 in second row in database...

Comment: Updated answer, please check now

Comment: but this insert only last value in table for ex - if i put 501,505 and click save then it insert only 505 not also  501 in database...but i need both to insert like 501,505 in two rows

Comment: In for loop, have you added a condition as `<=` & `$i = 1`? I have updated my answer for those conditions too.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? For 501,505 i will insert two rows in the database with `column1` value set to 501 and 505 respectively.

```
$column1 = $_POST['column1']; // Removed trailing space
$arr     = explode(",", rtrim($column1 , ', '));

foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $insertrow = $database->insertRow(
        "INSERT INTO table (column1) VALUES  (:column1)",
        array(':column1' => $value))
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what $min and $max are used for?

If you want to insert n rows, where n equals to the values in your array you just write:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {...
```

Comment: sir this insert only 1 and 2 in database if there are 2 values in my textbox bit i need to insert values not count of values .....for ex-  i need when i put 501,505, in textbox then it insert 501 in first row and 505 in second row in database...

Comment: this doesn't insert nothing, I just pointed out that to solve your "multiple rows" problem you have to change your `for` to iterate all the values in the array... you can access the "current value" by writing: `$arr[$i]`, which first going to be `501` and then `505`, so you will insert two different rows, each one with a value

Comment: notice that `$i` must be equal to `0` to iterate the whole array, this because if your array length is 2, the actual values positions are 0 and 1, so you must start accessing it at position 0 (the first value) and then at position 1 (the second value)